# Creating EC2 AMI Image

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to create an AMI of my instance but I'm frightened by the following prompt on AWS:

```
The instance you're using as a template for a new image has the following volumes:
/dev/sda1, vol-a9 (15 GiB), will delete on termination
Total size of EBS volumes: 15 GiB.
When you create an EBS image an EBS snapshot will also be created for each of the above volumes.
```

Now when it says that the EBS volume will delete on termination, does it mean termination of the script that creates the AMI or just when I terminate the Instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [post on AWS developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=225069) that sheds light to this.

> > > Delete on termination is a flag that can be turned off, which will remove the volume if the instance itself is terminated. Your current EBS volume will not be lost unless you terminate your current instance. Creating an image will only restart your current instance (You can disable that too, but not recommended to ensure consistency)

Comment: Thanks Jahufar, this is exactly what I needed to hear